# jquery ui sortable nested multi level menu order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to do `multi-level` `nested` `jQuery UI` `Sortable` menu reorder, but everything mess. Its ok on single level, but when i try to change a depth its fail.

My code:
http://jsfiddle.net/c7PGP/5/

html:

```
<ul class="sortable list-unstyled" id="sortable">
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">Index</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">About Us</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">Portfoion</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">Services</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled">
            <li>
                <div class="block block-title">Design</div>
                <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="block block-title">Develope</div>
                <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="block block-title">SEO</div>
                <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="block block-title">Support</div>
                <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- /.menu-sortable -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">Contact</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
    </li>
</ul><!-- /.menu-sortable -->
```

JS:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({ 
    connectWith:    '.sortable',
    cursor:         'move',
    placeholder:    'sortable-placeholder',
    handle:         '.block-title',
    cursorAt:       { left: 150, top: 17 },
    tolerance:      'pointer',
    scroll:         false,
    zIndex:         9999,
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();
```

There is solution here: [How to make jQuery UI sortable with nested dropdown menu work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101530/how-to-make-jquery-ui-sortable-with-nested-dropdown-menu-work), but i don't want another plugin.

**UPDATE:**
The problem: Drag `Index` into `SEO`. They both have `<ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>`

Comment: "but everything mess" is not a problem description. What exactly is not working? i'm able to move items between different levels...

Comment: @TilwinJoy Can you drop Index into SEO? SEO have inner ul.sortable, but when i try to drag/drop there its not possible.

Comment: The other problem is, when i drag all out of Services is not possible to put them inside.

Comment: There is a vibration like behaviour for placeholder when moving `index` or  `about us` into `services`. Have you solved it ?

Comment: Are you looking for nested lists like => Services->SEO->Index ?

Answer (score 2):

I added this to your style sheet on the fiddle:

```
.sortable ul { 
   padding: 5px;
}
```

It solves the issue with not being able to add to the depth.  I also recommend changing your JavaScript slightly by removing the tolerance parameter which makes adding to the depth a little easier.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({ 
    connectWith:    '.sortable',
    cursor:         'move',
    placeholder:    'sortable-placeholder',
    handle:         '.block-title',
    cursorAt:       { left: 150, top: 17 },
    /*tolerance:      'pointer',*/
    scroll:         false,
    zIndex:         9999,
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();
```

If the spacing is too wide you can reduce the padding to 3px, but anything lower than that becomes increasingly difficult to manage the depth levels.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `tolerance` from `pointer` to `intersect` which reduced the vibration while dragging.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({ 
    appendTo: "#sortable",
    connectWith:    '.sortable',
    cursor:         'move',
    placeholder:    'sortable-placeholder',
    handle:         '.block-title',
    cursorAt:       { left: 150, top: 17 },
    tolerance:      'intersect',
    scroll:         false,
    zIndex:         9999
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();
```

Also, added some style which allows you to add items below the sub items too which is given below,

```
.list-unstyled { 
   padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with spacing for the nesting to happen, use the code below and you will have to tilt to the right a bit and the nesting works

CSS:

```
.block {
    margin: 5px 0;
    border: 1px solid #f1e8e2;
    background: #fff;
}
.block-title {
  font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4c4743;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
.sortable {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.ui-sortable-helper {
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 3px 5px 0;
    width: 300px!important;
    height: 30px!important;
}
.sortable-placeholder {
    height: 30px;
    background: #e3dcd7;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.sortable ul { 
   padding: 7px;
   margin-left: 12px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({ 
    connectWith:    '.sortable',
    cursor:         'move',
    placeholder:    'sortable-placeholder',
    handle:         '.block-title',
    cursorAt:       { left: 150, top: 17 },
    scroll:         false,
    zIndex:         9999,
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following properties improves the drag/drop quite a bit:

```js
distance:        25
delay:           100
forceHelperSize: true
```

Combining those with [Tom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3842634/tom-hinz) padding logic, gives us the following demo:

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({ 
    connectWith:    '.sortable',
    cursor:         'move',
    placeholder:    'sortable-placeholder',
    handle:         '.block-title',
    scroll:         false,
    distance:           25,
    delay:                  100,
    forceHelperSize: true
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();
```

```css
.block {margin: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #f1e8e2; background: #fff; } 
.block-title {font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #4c4743; padding: 0 10px; height: 33px; line-height: 33px; position: relative; }
.sortable {list-style: none; padding-left: 0; }
.sortable ul {margin-left: 25px; }
.ui-sortable-helper {box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 3px 5px 0; width: 300px!important; height: 33px!important; }
.sortable-placeholder {height: 35px; background: #e3dcd7; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px; }

.sortable ul { 
   padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sortable list-unstyled" id="sortable">
    <li><div class="block block-title">Index</div><ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul></li>
    <li><div class="block block-title">About Us</div><ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul></li>
    <li><div class="block block-title">Portfoion</div><ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul></li>
    <li><div class="block block-title">Services</div><ul class="sortable list-unstyled"><li><div class="block block-title">Design</div><ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul></li>

    <li> <div class="block block-title">Develope</div> <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul> </li>
    <li> <div class="block block-title">SEO</div> <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul> </li>
    <li> <div class="block block-title">Support</div> <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul> </li> </ul> </li>
    <li> <div class="block block-title">Contact</div> <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will just work fine if you add up the new list items in this way.

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({ 
    connectWith:    '.sortable',
    cursor:         'move',
    placeholder:    'sortable-placeholder',
    handle:         '.block-title',
    cursorAt:       { left: 150, top: 17 },
    tolerance:      'pointer',
    scroll:         false,
    zIndex:         9999,
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();
```

```css
.block {
    margin: 5px 0;
    border: 1px solid #f1e8e2;
    background: #fff;
}
.block-title {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4c4743;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    position: relative;
}
.sortable {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.sortable ul {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.ui-sortable-helper {
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 3px 5px 0;
    width: 300px!important;
    height: 33px!important;
}
.sortable-placeholder {
    height: 35px;
    background: #e3dcd7;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sortable list-unstyled" id="sortable">
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">Index</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">About Us</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">Portfoion</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">Services</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled">
            <li>
                <div class="block block-title">Design</div>
                <ul class="sortable list-unstyled">
                  <li>
                    <div class="block block-title">Web Design</div>
                    <ul class="sortable list-unstyled">
                      <li>
                        <div class="block block-title">Post Design</div>
                        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="block block-title">Develope</div>
                <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="block block-title">SEO</div>
                <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="block block-title">Support</div>
                <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- /.menu-sortable -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="block block-title">Contact</div>
        <ul class="sortable list-unstyled"></ul>
    </li>
</ul><!-- /.menu-sortable -->
```