# How do I create an unlimited nested sortable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I built a simple sortable list without sub lists with jquery-ui. How can I add an option to nest an list item without having sub ul's allready

```
<div id="sorter">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2uup4jdd/

If I add a sub ul with html I can sort it as well but I can't **create** new ul's / sub list items in the runtime environment.

```
<div id="sorter">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item Sub</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2uup4jdd/1/

Is there a way to activate that? Any other ideas?

Comment: I use [the nestedSortable plugin](https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable) for that. ([Demo](http://ilikenwf.github.io/example.html)). Works like a charm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make jQuery UI sortable with nested dropdown menu work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101530/how-to-make-jquery-ui-sortable-with-nested-dropdown-menu-work)

Comment: @LinkinTED thanks that looks exaktly what I am looking for. [at] ilyas-mimouni it's definitively not a duplicated entry. I searched for a solution for a unlimited nested sorter without prepared placeholders in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use the [nestedSortable](https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable) plugin for that. ([Demo](http://ilikenwf.github.io/example.html)). Works like a charm.

Thanks that will do the work :)
It seems far more complicated with unlimited nested list items.